# PyQt in Squish IDE

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt5, squish

I use Squish IDE in python for automatic tests on Qt Application. During the execution of test case, I want create an external graphic interface to give information test. I have installed PyQt5 package in my environment, but when I import the library ("from PyQt5 import QtWidgets) i obtain this error and the program terminates:
("Detail ImportError: DLL load failed while importing QtWidgets: %1 non è un'applicazione di Win32 valida.")

Is it possible to use PyQt in squish IDE to create an external interface?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Behind the covers the Squish IDE is simply executing your test suites/cases/scripts via squishrunner. squishrunner hosts a Python interpreter, and creates its own event loop for continuous communication with other Squish components. This leaves no room for third party event loops, since they can interfere with Squish' operations.

Alternatives are, using the [testInteraction functions](https://doc.froglogic.com/squish/latest/rgs-squish.html#rgs-testinteraction) that Squish provides, or [executing an external application](https://kb.froglogic.com/squish/howto/executing-external-applications/) that does what you want.